# How to get an OpenLayers Vector Layer to always draw all features, regardless of zoom, range, etc?

Tags: openlayers

I have a huge polygon (20km x 100km) and I can't get it to render at zoom level greater than 15 or so.

It seems to be related to zoom level, because I have 20km and 100km lines drawn across the screen as a sanity check.  Zooming in to level 16, the polygon and the 100km lines disappear, but the 20km lines remain through level 17, then disappear at max zoom on level 18.  I have a pretty basic vector layer with mostly default settings:

```js
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('My Layer', {
    ratio: 10,
    alwaysInRange: true
});
```

## Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/9xKbh/

Comment: crossposted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70592

Comment: My temporary solution is to create a new polygon with outer bounds 5 times the map bounds.  Then it's within whatever threshold OL is using and shows up fine, and then I redraw with updated bounds on every map 'moveend' event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following into your script tag, placed somewhere after OpenLayers.js has been loaded (eg. on top of that JS Fiddle):

```
OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.prototype.MAX_PIXEL = Number.MAX_VALUE;
```

source: [open issues on GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/668)